# Usdc bep20 from trust wallet sent to usdc erc20 on metamask

Tags: metamask, stablecoins, trust, usdc

Please, I sent a bep20 usdc from my trust wallet account to an erc20 usdc or something like that on my metamask account since almost 24hr, but it's yet to reflect. Can someone kindly help with some guides, please?

Comment: I tried adding the bep20 contract address to custom tokens on metamask, but keeps bringing 'Personal contract address detected, but I got the address from coingecko and bscscan

Comment: Do you have the transaction hash? Did you try to send tokens from one chain to another? It is not possible to send tokens across blockchains without an intermediary like an exchange or a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

i did the same thing today. i sent USDC from trust wallet to my ETH metamask wallet and it never showed. I found the bscscan tx link in my trust wallet USDC history. i clicked that and copied the "Interacted with (to)" contract address. I then went on to my metamask wallet and installed the Binance smart chain network in metamask. once my wallet switched over to the binance network, i clicked on "add token" button just underneath my BNB amount. i pasted the contact address in to the custom token bar and voila, my USDC BEP 20 coins showed up. i hope this helps you or anyone else that find themselves in this problem. now i have to find a way to switch my bep20 USDC to erc20 without a vpn. cheers!

Comment: I tried this but the balance on MetaMask is 0. Why wouldn't you use the ending address? Interact with (to) is the middle man no?